# How do I install tuleap on windows7?

Tags: windows-7, tuleap

How do I install tuleap on windows7?

Is it possible to run or install tuleap on windows like in localhost with xampp?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is it possible to run or install tuleap on windows?

No it is not. It requires a Linux server.

> To install Tuleap you will need a fully dedicated server. It can be
>   virtualized or physical. It is not recommended to install Tuleap on a
>   server that hosts other applications. Tuleap provides a full suite of
>   software and is deeply integrated with its host system. Installing
>   Tuleap on a mutualized server will certainly cause probleme in both
>   Tuleap and your other applications.
>
> Tuleap can be installed on linux x86_64 systems: - Centos or Redhat
>   6.x is the recommended platform - Centos or Redhat 5.x with php 5.3 is still maintained but not recommended anymore - Debian 7.x is in alpha
>   version. It is not recommended and maintained. Use it at your own
>   risks.
>
> The server will need an Internet connection as it will download
>   external packages
>
> You can have a look at the Installation checklist here:
>
> https://tuleap.net/wiki/index.php?pagename=TuleapInstallationChecklist&group_id=101

Source [Full Installation](http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html)